# How country>state>city like database should be used to be logic?

Tags: google-maps, location, state, country, city

I am writing a web site which has to frequently use that kind of comboboxes.
I am little confuse while there was lots of different and clumsy databases on the net. The confusion is the selection of the sub location of the countires. Some countries has states, some constituent countries (ex:UK) and  some provinces. When I select the first type of country the second selectbox will be filled by its states for second type of country sub countries and for third type of the provinces. As it is seen from the situation it is not logic the province is enough in size but the states or countries are large compared by provinces. How can I handle this problem.

I need to force the user to select from preset list since the item selected form second select box will have the location data to group and arrange the entries by its selection and I decide to not go deeper than province to prevent showing of lots of markers on google map. When I clicked to that pin it should pops the infobox containg the items releated with that province.

Note: I used the word province since I am living in Turkey its first administrative divisons are the provinces. Arizona or texas is much greater than Istanbul.

I can change my way if you suggest an other useful solution for this kind of problem.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Might be better if you have different logic for each country. OR just allow selection from dropdown list of `city, country`.

Comment: I couldn't get your point. I am already using dropdown boxes to select first country than the city as second box. but when I select US as country the city box will be filled with states for now. Some where like myip.ms for UK the citis are used for second box but in geonames.org sub countries are used. If I choose a way then I need a database or a way to make my own db with little effort for releated use way.

Thanks your comment :).

Answer (score 0):

Digitial Road Maps from the both existing professional map provider solve it that way.

Each country has up to 8 Adminstration levels.

Level 1 is always the country

Then it depends on the country how many levels it has.
for each level a country uses there are borders available.

Asuming that country administration borders have a strong hierarchical order:

Then just define which admin levels a country uses, and provide a list of all names of each adminstration unit.

You also may want to read how OpenStreetMap does this, and probably take the list of administartion names form their Database.

For your web page:
After the user selects to country, you have to look up how many admin levels the country has, then create the combo boxes and fill them as soon the previous admin level is selected.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand what you meen. If you can provide me some links or live examples I'll be happy. I don't want to give more then 2/3 comboxboxes for selections. :/.

Comment: Then take the top most 2 or 3 depending on the number of adminstration levels. Search for TeleAtlas MultiNet format, I don't know if it is public, otheriwse search for "wiki administration levels".

Comment: Then I don't know  yet how to access to 2. or 3. admin levels of each country to make a database with their locations and zipcodes. :/